# Get id of max value in group

Tags: sql

I have a table and i would like to gather the id of the items from each group with the max value on a column but i have a problem.

```
SELECT group_id, MAX(time) 
FROM mytable
GROUP BY group_id
```

This way i get the correct rows but i need the id:

```
SELECT id,group_id,MAX(time)
FROM mytable
GROUP BY id,group_id
```

This way i got all the rows. How could i achieve to get the ID of max value row for time from each group?

Sample Data

```
id = 1, group_id = 1, time = 2014.01.03
id = 2, group_id = 1, time = 2014.01.04
id = 3, group_id = 2, time = 2014.01.04
id = 4, group_id = 2, time = 2014.01.02
id = 5, group_id = 3, time = 2014.01.01
```

and from that i should get id: 2,3,5
Thanks!

Comment: remove "id" from group by clause

Comment: Mysql has laxer group by policy than other DBMS,you can leave columns out of GROUP BY or aggregate functions.

Comment: Explain with some sample data

Comment: I cant remove it kwelsan because it says than it not a valid group by

Answer (score 13, accepted):

Use your working query as a sub-query, like this:

```
SELECT `id` 
FROM `mytable` 
WHERE (`group_id`, `time`) IN (
  SELECT `group_id`, MAX(`time`) as `time` 
  FROM `mytable`
  GROUP BY `group_id`
)
```

Comment: will not work if the time values are the same for multiple rows

Comment: This won't work in SQL Server, you can only have 1 column where a condition is expected, not a group.

Comment: Almost, but as @AnandTripathi points out, this breaks when you have multiple rows with different ids but the same date.

Answer (score 11):

Have a look at the below demo

```
DROP TABLE IF EXISTS mytable;

CREATE TABLE mytable(id INT , group_id INT , time_st DATE);

INSERT INTO mytable VALUES(1, 1, '2014-01-03'),(2, 1, '2014-01-04'),(3, 2, '2014-01-04'),(4, 2, '2014-01-02'),(5, 3, '2014-01-01');

/** Check all data **/
SELECT * FROM mytable;
+------+----------+------------+
| id   | group_id | time_st    |
+------+----------+------------+
|    1 |        1 | 2014-01-03 |
|    2 |        1 | 2014-01-04 |
|    3 |        2 | 2014-01-04 |
|    4 |        2 | 2014-01-02 |
|    5 |        3 | 2014-01-01 |
+------+----------+------------+


/** Query for Actual output**/

SELECT 
    id
FROM
    mytable 
JOIN
    ( 
      SELECT group_id, MAX(time_st) as max_time 
      FROM mytable GROUP BY group_id 
    ) max_time_table 
ON mytable.group_id = max_time_table.group_id AND mytable.time_st = max_time_table.max_time;    
+------+
| id   |
+------+
|    2 |
|    3 |
|    5 |
+------+
```

Comment: This works in SQL Server, whereas the accepted answer doesn't.

Comment: This will bring problems if there are 2 rows with the same group_id and time_st

Answer (score 1):

You can try this:

```
;WITH cte
AS (
    SELECT t.id, t.group_id, TIME, ROW_NUMBER() OVER (
            PARTITION BY t.group_id ORDER BY t.time DESC
            ) AS r
    FROM mytable t
    )
SELECT c.id, c.group_id, c.time
FROM cte c
WHERE c.r = 1
```

In case of duplictes in the *time* column above query will give you a random single row from among the duplicates. You can attempt to resolve the conflicts by adding aditional column or using other windows functions like RANK() or DENSE_RANK().

Answer (score 0):

When multiple groups may contain the same value, you could use

```sql
SELECT subq.id
FROM (SELECT id,
             value,
             MAX(time) OVER (PARTITION BY group_id) as max_time
      FROM mytable) as subq
WHERE subq.time = subq.max_time
```

The subquery here generates a new column (`max_time`) that contains the maximum time per group. We can then filter on `time` and `max_time` being identical. Note that this still returns multiple rows per group if the maximum value occurs multiple time within the same group.

Full example:

```sql
CREATE TABLE test (
  id INT,
  group_id INT,
  value INT
);
INSERT INTO test (id, group_id, value) VALUES (1, 1, 100);
INSERT INTO test (id, group_id, value) VALUES (2, 1, 200);
INSERT INTO test (id, group_id, value) VALUES (3, 1, 300);
INSERT INTO test (id, group_id, value) VALUES (4, 2, 100);
INSERT INTO test (id, group_id, value) VALUES (5, 2, 300);
INSERT INTO test (id, group_id, value) VALUES (6, 2, 200);
INSERT INTO test (id, group_id, value) VALUES (7, 3, 300);
INSERT INTO test (id, group_id, value) VALUES (8, 3, 200);
INSERT INTO test (id, group_id, value) VALUES (9, 3, 100);

select * from test;
 id | group_id | value 
----+----------+-------
  1 |        1 |   100
  2 |        1 |   200
  3 |        1 |   300
  4 |        2 |   100
  5 |        2 |   300
  6 |        2 |   200
  7 |        3 |   300
  8 |        3 |   200
  9 |        3 |   100
(9 rows)

SELECT subq.id
FROM (SELECT id,
             value,
             MAX(value) OVER (partition by group_id) as max_value
      FROM test) as subq
WHERE subq.value = subq.max_value;
 id 
----
  3
  5
  7
(3 rows)
```

Answer (score 0):

```
SELECT MAX(id) FROM mytable INNER JOIN (
SELECT group_id, MAX(TIME) AS maxtime
FROM mytable
GROUP BY group_id
) t ON mytable.group_id = t.group_id AND mytable.TIME = t.maxtime GROUP BY mytable.group_id
```

Comment: Remember that Stack Overflow isn't just intended to solve the immediate problem, but also to help future readers find solutions to similar problems, which requires understanding the underlying code. This is especially important for members of our community who are beginners, and not familiar with the syntax. Given that, **can you [edit] your answer to include an explanation of what you're doing** and why you believe it is the best approach?